# Prevent textarea on focus scroll to top on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent textarea fields on mobile devices scroll to top on focus. If one clicks inside a textarea which is higher than the viewport, it scrolls to top of textarea field on focus.

Tried ..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('textarea').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var cursor = event.pageY;
        window.scrollTo(0, cursor); 

    });
});
```